# Use standard error of mean or population distribution?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, statistical-inference

Question:

> Marks obtained by certain number of students are assumed to be
>   normally distributed with mean 65 and variance 25. If three students
>   are taken at random, what is the probability that exactly two of them
>   will have marks over 70?

The textbook way to solve it is:
Finding the probability (p) that a student gets more than 70 marks. Then find $3(C)2 * p^2 *  q$

To find the probability(p) the solution first calculates z=$(70-65)/5$

My confusion is that why did it use the standard deviation of the population(5) instead of using mean of the sampling distribution of sample mean which would have been $5/sqrt(3)$?

In general how do I know when to use what because a lot of questions related to normal distribution first calculate the standard error of mean to calculate the z score.

Comment: What does this have to do with the sample mean?  The condition is that exactly two have marks over $70$.  That says nothing about the sample mean.  If the question was about the sum of those students' marks, you might look at the distribution of the sample mean.

Comment: http://stattrek.com/sampling/sampling-distribution.aspx
Consider the question given in the above link in Example 1: It requires to calculate weight of average student but it uses standard error of mean to calculate the z score rather than the population s.d like in this similar question.
Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the stattrek example, you are not told the true distribution of the population of students. You only know the average weight and the sd. I take a sample of 50 students and then take the average of these 50 students. I call that $\bar X$. I need to know what is the probability that the average weight $\bar X$ of a sampled student will be less than 75 pounds. Well, when you take the average of 50 students, you are **adding** up 50 different draws from the population. The CLT implies that $\bar X$ will (approximately) follow a normal distribution. In order to use the normal approximation, you need the average of $\bar X$ and the standard distribution of $\bar X$.
It turns out that the average of $\bar X$ is the true population average
$$\text{avg of }\bar X = \mu_{\bar X} = 80 \text{ lbs.}$$
Using higher statistics, you can show that the standard deviation of 
$\bar X$ is
$$\sigma_{\bar X} = \frac{20}{\sqrt{50}}.$$
I ignored the correction factor. I believe this is called the **square root law**. It is just a fact you have to take for granted in lower stats. Now, you have the average of $\bar X$ and the sd of $\bar X$. Next, it is just a matter of using the usual techniques to use the normal approximation.

Comment: No problem. Up votes and check marks would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: Right now I don't have the reputation to upvote but as soon as I have it, I will come back to upvote it :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you were given information about **all** the students taking the test, you know the true population mean and standard deviation. In other words, the problem is trying to get you to relate a score of 70 to the area under the curve. The area under the curve to the left of 70 represents the percentage $p$ of students who got a 70 or worse. In other words, if I randomly pick a student from the class, the chance that they did worse than 70 is $p$. A similar case can be made for the right side of 70. Maybe in terms of a diagram,
$$\text{test score} \Longleftrightarrow z\text{-score} \Longleftrightarrow \text{area under cruve } p.$$

Finally, since each student is independent of each other, you have $n=3$ independent trials with probability $p$ of success. This is a binomial distribution. Hence, the answer the book provided.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have posted my doubt as a comment to my question.